# In a distributed databases, in what way is data replicated?

Tags: networking, replication, cluster-computing

I'm confused as to how replication works in a distributed database.
For instance, is the replication such that in site A (at location A) there is an exact replica of the data in site B? Or is it "replicated" in that site A has different data than site B but sites A and B have data that CAN BE clustered and replicated between sites A and B?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your database is distributed, what level of redundancy you are looking for, and what technology you are using. With dbShards, you can distribute your database for performance and scalability (all at location A) across many servers (say servers 1, 2, and 3). Then you can replicate locally to cover for server failure (creating backups of 1, 2, 3). But you can also set up a second location with a complete replica of the cluster at location A for full disaster recovery. You can learn more here: http://www.dbshards.com/dbshards/replication-failover/